# Using "hate on", as compared to "hate"

Tags: informal-language

How is the verb, "hate on", used differently from "hate"? More specifically,

- How formal is it?
- How polite is it?
- Who would you say it to?
- In what contexts are "hate on" preferred over "hate"?
- In what cases are "is/are/am hating on" to just "hate on," preferred?

Comment: We aren't a polling site. Your question clearly reads like a poll. We can answer the question directly without giving out personal information.

Comment: Related at EL&U: *[Origin of “hating on”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/)* and *[Origin of phrasal verb “love on”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120433)*.

Answer (score 2):

To hate on someone is to express dislike of or criticize them (or one of their characteristics) usually because of jealousy. So it is an action.
This is more slang than standard English, but I feel like it is becoming a popular expression. "Don't hate on my boyfriend, he's not that bad." "I know I shouldn't hate on her, but she drives me crazy". *This is like talk bad about.*

Hate is standard English, used to describe something you really really don't like. It is a very strong word to chose. "I hate my math class."

See here for more specific info:
http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/hate-on